# Is there a way to toggle the bootstrap responsive collapse menu upwards instead of downwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I was wondering if there was a way to toggle the bootstrap responsive nav upwards instead of down.  I don't have a fixed bottom nav but still wanted it to go up instead of down and didn't know if this was in their framework or if there was a way with javascript or jquery to do so.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? First thing about Stack Overflow; if you want help, show some effort.

Comment: I cant find anything on how to do this that is why I posted the question here to see if anyone knew of a page or a technique to do so.  The only thing that I can find is that the fixed bottom navbar has this built in. I know a little about javascipt but im not a javascript pro or anything like that I assumed this was a fairly simple question with maybe a simple answer that I just couldn't find any documentation on.  I wouldn't have posted the question if I could find documentation on it.  I assume that is what this forum us for to find someone who can point me in the right direction correct.

Comment: You are half-correct on the point of Stack Overflow. It's an archive of questions and answers, and the best way to get an answer is to post a good question. Your question has gone an hour with no activity, meaning people are looking at it and disregarding at as a no effort question. For this kind of issue, you need to show what you have tried. If you haven't tried anything, and have only searched for a quick and dirty answer to this exact issue, then you may want to rethink your approach. To point you in the right direction; try something *first*, and if you can't get a solution, then ask.